# SONAR_HOST_URL not reachable in bitbucket pipeline sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to integrate the sonarqube to bitbucket pipeline, and have following code there

```
 - pipe: sonarsource/sonarqube-scan:1.0.0
              variables:
                SONAR_HOST_URL: ${SONAR_HOST_URL}
                SONAR_TOKEN: ${SONAR_TOKEN}
            - pipe: sonarsource/sonarqube-quality-gate:1.0.0
              variables:
                SONAR_TOKEN: ${SONAR_TOKEN}
```

and I am getting error

> SonarQube server [$SONAR_HOST_URL] can not be reached

I first tried setting localhost:9000, which is running at my local server, got this error, then I give website url, still getting same error,

what should I give **SONAR_HOST_URL**

Any help,
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

> SonarQube server [$SONAR_HOST_URL] can not be reached

means `SONAR_HOST_URL` is not defined in the CI environment. You want to use `Repository settings` -> `Repository variables` to add both host url & token (ensure `Secured` check box is set for token).

P.S. The host url should be publicly accessible. It won't work for `localhost:9000` because the Bitbucket CI has not\ way to connect to the instance of the sonarqube server running on your local dev box.